# IPN do not send response for Completed Status

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We have developed a IPN listener and it is successfully receiving responses from Paypal .

**Problem** : IPN is responding with a payment_status as "Pending" even when the transaction is completed(We crosschecked it in the seller account).

If we are refunding the IPN is responding with proper payment status( Refund ) .

Can anyone tell that what are the points we may be missing as we have to write the core logic only when the payment_status is "Completed".

**Note** : We are using sandbox paypal.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the any transaction id which shows status as "pending" in your IPN?

Comment: txn_id is like 1KV49447100814057

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have turned on the "Payment Review" for your sandbox account due to which the Payment goes into the review status and it gets into the completed within 24 hour . So , if you want the status to come as "completed" you need to login to the developer.paypal.com --> Dashboard --> Sandbox --> Accounts. Click on your sandbox email address --> Profile --> Settings . You will see the option "Payment review" , you need to turn it off .

Once its done you will receive the payment with completed status .

You can refer the screen shot below :

http://content.screencast.com/users/Eshan26Jain/folders/Default/media/bb944b14-ee33-4914-a259-a06790258773/2014-11-13_19-01-05.png

[image]

Comment: I dont find any option of payment review on sandbox paypal account --> settings (Seller)..

Comment: I did these settings as per your updated answer but still no luck.